# create a date column from start & end unixtimestamps and link to other data

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am working in Postgres 13.3 and I have the following:

**TABLE DEFINITIONS**

```
create table clusters (
  cluster_id serial primary key,
  cluster_name varchar
);

create table jobs (
  job_id serial primary key,
  cluster_id int not null,
  job_name varchar not null,
  constraint fk_cluster foreign key(cluster_id) references clusters(cluster_id)
);

create table clients (
  client_id serial primary key,
  client_name varchar not null
);

create table jobs_clients (
  job_id int not null,
  client_id int not null
);

create table jobs_info (
  job_info_id serial,
  job_id int not null,
  start_time bigint, -- microseconds unix timestamp
  end_time bigint, -- microseconds unix timestamp
  duration bigint, -- result of end_time - start_time
  primary key(job_info_id, job_id)
);
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

I would like to get a date column from the above, and for each client list the following:

```
| cluster_name | date        | client_name | number_of_jobs | average_job_duration |
| ------------ | ----------- | ----------- | -------------- | -------------------- |
| MAIN_DC0_K1  | 2019-10-23  | client 01   | 1              | 0.5                  |
| MAIN_DC0_K1  | 2019-10-23  | client 02   | 2              | 1.2                  |
```

The average job duration is in hours.

**CURRENT QUERY**

```
select 
c.cluster_name, 
j.job_name,
cl.client_name,
ji.start_time,
ji.end_time,
ji.duration
from clusters c 
inner join jobs j on c.cluster_id = j.cluster_id
inner join jobs_clients jc on jc.job_id = j.job_id
inner join clients cl on cl.client_id = jc.client_id
inner join jobs_info ji on ji.job_id = j.job_id;
```

I am struggling in building the date column, I'm not really sure how to go about that. The date column should only list dates where data actually exists.

I have also created a [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oWDas9bBXfj34BZs2bvV2Z/0) to make things easier.

**Clarification:**

My issue is not converting microseconds to a regular timestamp. What I'm struggling with is getting the date as a column with the number of jobs per client.

Comment: If you are going to do date/timestamp math then  make your life easier and use `date` or `timestamp` columns. If your data is coming in as epoch microsecond you can convert it to a Postgres `timestamp` using `to_timestamp(usec_val/1000)`.  Not sure what the `duration` field is for as it is a calculated field. Unless you want to use [Generated columns](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/ddl-generated-columns.html) which is available in Postgres 12+.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver in case of unix time in microseconds it should be divided by 1000000 instead of 1000 to convert with `to_timestamp()`.

Comment: @AkhileshMishra.  Yeah, had milliseconds in my brain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgres `to_timestamp(epoch time in seconds)` can be used to convert your epoch time into normal timestamp. Since your unix time is in microsecond, you have to divide it by 1000000 to get the second. Further you can convert the timestamp into date.

To convert the average duration into hours, simply divide the duration by 1000000 to get the seconds and then by 3600 to get the hours.
You can try below query.

```
-- basic select
select 
c.cluster_name, 
to_timestamp(ji.start_time/1000000)::date,
cl.client_name,
count(*),
(avg(duration)/1000000)/3600

from clusters c 
inner join jobs j on c.cluster_id = j.cluster_id
inner join jobs_clients jc on jc.job_id = j.job_id
inner join clients cl on cl.client_id = jc.client_id
inner join jobs_info ji on ji.job_id = j.job_id
group by 1,2,3;
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=26a070879293f39e1cc57dfaa6456869)